# Keep AngularJS responsive while resolving controller dependencies

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, dependencies, promise, angular-ui-router

AngularJS stops processing UI events while it waits for any promised controller dependencies to resolve. If any of these dependencies rely on an API call that hangs, the application becomes unresponsive.

How do I design an AngularJS application that remains responsive while ui-router resolves external controller dependencies?

### CoffeeScript Example:

#### Route Definition for `/accounts/:account_id` that injects `accountBase`:

```
$stateProvider.state('accounts',
    abstract: true
    url: '/accounts/:account_id'
    templateUrl: "/views/accounts/index.html"
    resolve:
        accountBase: ($stateParams, $q, Restangular, $rootScope, Session) ->
            deferred = $q.defer()
            base = Restangular.one('accounts', $stateParams.account_id)
            base.get().then (result) ->
                console.log 'resolved accounts', result
                deferred.resolve(result)
            , (error) ->
                deferred.reject('cannot resolve user account')
            return deferred.promise
).state('users', ... # continues
```

#### Controller Example

```
app.controller 'DomainsCtrl', ['$scope', 'accountBase', ($scope, accountBase) ->
    # use resolved accountBase for further processing
    accountBase.get().then ->
        console.log 'do something here'
    return
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got many options when it comes to loading data in AngularJS. Here are 3 approaches that all have a different effect on rendering and visibility of data.

- Resolve (in a route or a state) - By definition, this halts rendering of the page until the all of the resolve values are finished loading. In your example, you return a promise, which ui-router will resolve before it begins rendering/execution of the controller function. In my experience, these are best used sparingly, as they result in a choppy experience.
- In your controller, use a $resource and bind the return value of a get/query directly to the $scope.

  ```
   var Foo = $resource('/api/foos'); // inject this into your controller

   // inside your controller function...
   $scope.foos = Foo.query();
  ```

  This will result in an empty object being placed on the $scope, which will be filled with data from the API call as soon as it is available. This may or may not be desirable depending on what you are displaying. In your template, you can check the $resolved property `ng-show="foos.$resolved"` in order to display some sort of visual cue that the data is loading. (Also, I'm not sure if Restangular offers this same sort of "empty object" return value, or if it only returns promises.)

  Worth noting: you can also use a resolve in the same way. Since an object will be returned (not a promise, though the object contains one), rendering/controller function execution will not be held up:

  ```
  resolve: {
      foos: function(Foo) {
          return Foo.query();
      }
  }
  ```
- Provide some default values for the data you want to display, then use a success function for a $http or $resource call to populate with real values.

  ```
  $scope.data = {
      stuff: "none yet",
      things: "still waiting"
  };

  // when the data is available, replace the defaults.
  Foo.get({id: 1}, function(data) {
      angular.extend($scope.data, data);  
  });
  ```

A couple other things worth noting:

- Cache the data so that you've got a stale copy available the next time the user visits that page/route. Stale data is often better than no data. You can use [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) for storing things in local storage for availability across sessions - very handy.
- To keep data around within the current session, use a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services), which are singletons, to hold on to a reference to your data. Anything that injects the service below will get the same instance of the object (an array in this case).

  ```
  angular.factory('ThingsThatProbablyWontChange', function($resource) {
      var Foo = $resource('/api/foos');

      return Foo.query();
  });
  ```

  This is a simplistic example, but you could return a wrapper object providing functions for manipulating/reloading the data.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

It's worth mentioning that your example code is bending over backward a bit to load the accountBase. Because you resolve the promise in resolve function with `deferred.resolve(base);`, your controller is injected with the already-resolved promise. For clarity, you could do `deferred.resolve(result);` instead so that the value of `result` gets injected directly into your controller.

I just looked at the [Restangular docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#quick-configuration-for-lazy-readers) and I see that you can return the $object property of the promise to get the same sort of "empty object to be filled" returned by $resource, which will resolve immediately without blocking rendering, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my sample code. I do typically resolve the result, not base.

Comment: Np. Did this solve your problem? If so, I'd appreciate it if you would accept the answer. If not, I'm happy to add detail or another alternative.